# Keep iframe in the middle of an image

Tags: html, css, iframe

So I have a web app that I would like users to view as if it was on an android/iphone. I have had a look at a few solutions all of which have at least one thing wrong with them. So my work around is to have said webapp load on the middle of an iframe which is in the middle of an image of a iphone that frames it. Ugly but for what I want it is perfect except the iframe moves around the screen depending on screen size so doesn't always sit in the middle of the frame.

What I have achieved so far.

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta name="keyword" content="key words, keywords" />
  <meta name="description" content="brief and to the point description of the web page." />
  <meta name="robots" content="all" />

  <style>
  #container {
position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 45%;
  width: 367px;
  height: 717px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -75px;
  }
  #browser {
  position: absolute;
  top: 23%;
  left: 46%;
  margin-top: -49px;
  margin-left: -64px;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
  </style>

  </head>
  <body style ="background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#C7000D),       to(#2E0002))"; >
  <div id="container"><img src="images/ip4.png" style=""></div>

  <iframe id="browser" src="http://server.com/index.php?id=5" width="320px"       height="482px" scrolling="no">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
  </iframe>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Any full proof methods to get the iframe smack in the middle of the image every time?

View current result here [images of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wc6gc.jpg)

Comment: A table within a table with 100% height and width. Maybe the cell inside center aligned? Yup, ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Why not break the phone image into three segments over three `div`s? Apply the top segment as the background image to the first div, apply the middle segment to the second div, and the bottom to the third. Give all three divs equal widths, apply a height to each div to match its corresponding image segment, and set each div's `margin` to `0px auto`. Finally, apply `display: block;` to the iframe and position it absolutely inside the second (middle) div. Finally, wrap all three divs in one large dive with a height matching the combined height of all three divs. Then, to position this div in the middle of the page, position it absolutely, give it `top: 50%; margin-top: -[one-half of height]px; left: 50%; margin-left: -[one-half of width]px;` and set your `body` element to to have a `min-width` and `min-height` greater or equal to the width and height of the big div.